# Font smoothing in Wine

Tags: linux, wine, anti-aliasing

I've recently switched from Windows to Linux (elementary OS), and installed Notepad++ with Wine.

It works fine, but looks like Windows 95.

[image: Screenshot]

I tried setting [registry settings](http://www.wine-reviews.net/wine-reviews/tips-n-tricks/how-to-enable-font-anti-aliasing-in-wine.html) to make the fonts look better, and everything from [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=4456).

I also tried compiling Wine with [this patch](http://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=16745) applied.

Nothing makes a difference to the font rendering.

How can I enable font hinting or anti-aliasing in Wine?

Comment: What version of wine?

Comment: @MichaelHampton I'm using Wine version 1.5.15.

Comment: Try using a stable (1.4.x) version instead?

Comment: @MichaelHampton From what I've heard, font smoothing stopped working in v1.1.x, but I will try 1.4.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I looked at the screenshot in the Software Center (v1.4), and the font is aliased / not smoothed.

Comment: I'm out of ideas. I only play games with Wine. :)

Comment: Have you considered switching to a native editor? Notepad++ isn't bad, but it's not anything special. Look into something like Geany.

Comment: @ssmy I **need** FTP integration, and I don't think that Geany has that. Notepad++ does, and it automatically uploads modified files.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: I solved my own problem :-)

Comment: @ssmy I don't need to switch editors now, because I managed to get the fonts to look okay in Wine :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It turned out to be easier than I thought: font substitution.

[image: Smooth fonts in Notepad++/Wine]

---

Here's how to make the fonts look better:

1. Navigate to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Wine\Fonts\Replacements` in the Wine registry editor (`wine regedit`).
2. Create a new string value called `Segoe UI`, and set its value to `Droid Sans` (or any other sans-serif font name).
3. Naviagte to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes`.
4. Create a new string called `MS Shell Dlg` and set its value to a sans-serif font (I used Droid Sans again). Create another string called `MS Shell Dlg 2` and do the same. [[source]](http://onhax.wordpress.com/2010/01/08/how-to-change-windows-xp-default-system-font/)
5. Close the registry editor and run `wineboot` to restart Wine.

Great! Smooth fonts!

**But:** the monospace font in Notepad++ is still jagged.

The fix for that is quite easy, too:

1. Open the Style Configurator (Settings -> Style Configurator).
2. Choose the font and font size that you want, then check 'Enable global font' and 'Enable global font size' to activate the settings. I chose Droid Sans Mono as the font.

---

I hope that this will help someone else too.

Comment: I've been haunted by font smoothing not working in Wine for some time (all scripts and patches seems to not work anymore)... but editing these registry entries did the trick! Thank you very much for you finding.