# Disable font smoothing in Wine

Tags: linux, fonts, wine, anti-aliasing

I have the opposite problem of this: [Font smoothing in Wine](https://superuser.com/q/491373/681763)

Fonts that are rendered the Windows way look blurry and have their colours offset, like on Windows, so I want to disable font smoothing completely.

What I've tried:

- Regedit keys `ClientSideAntiAliasWithRender` and `ClientSideAntiAliasWithCore` in `HKCU/Software/Wine/X11 Driver`
- `fontsmooth=disable` in `winetricks`
- Font substitution from [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/491990/681763), both with a Linux font and a Windows font
- tested `wineboot` and real reboot on all of these attempts

Results: None. Both the menus in Notepad++ and the text in Wordpad are still blurry and look exactly the same as before.

I'm using Wine 5.8 on Manjaro 20.0.1.

Comment: I've found a partial solution, using `xrdb`. But that gets reset on boot. I'm currently looking for what does that and then I'll check if only this one specific setting can be changed without loading the entire file again.

Comment: In Wine regedit, inside the registry key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop`, set `FontSmoothing` to `0` to disable.

Comment: @harrymc That's just an alternative way to do my attempt #2. It's nice to know that that's possible, because the Winetricks GUI is annoying and needs to be installed to use that method, but it doesn't solve the problem. I'm close to my own answer, I'll post that soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wine apparently respects the system's font smoothing setting, no matter what is set anywhere else. This setting is for example located in "Look and feel"→"Appearance"→"Fonts"→"Rendering"→"Details"→"Smoothing" in the settings of my system (Manjaro, Mate desktop environment).

The good news is that Wine does not update font smoothing of a program while it is running. Therefore it's possible to disable font smoothing, start the program to run with Wine and enable font smoothing again, with no effects on the rest of the system.
The bad news is that the way to do this depends on the desktop environment (and probably also distribution), so this answer can only cover very few of them.

An example script for Mate is this:

```
gsettings set org.mate.font-rendering antialiasing 'none'
env WINEPREFIX="/home/fabian/.wine" wine C:\\windows\\command\\start.exe /Unix /home/fabian/.wine/dosdevices/c:/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/Start\ Menu/Programs/Notepad++.lnk "$1"
sleep 1
gsettings set org.mate.font-rendering antialiasing 'rgba'
```

The second command is just the start command for Notepad++, like it gets auto-generated in the main menu when installing Notepad++ using `pacman`, except that I added »`"$1"`« so that it can be used to open files from a file manager. This seems to also work with multiple files.
If I remember correctly, using »`"$@"`« or »`$@`« caused some kind of issue, so I'm leaving it like this for now.

A script for more general use, which first reads the setting and later restores it how it was, is this:

```
antialiasing=`gsettings get org.mate.font-rendering antialiasing`
gsettings set org.mate.font-rendering antialiasing 'none'
# insert your Wine command here
sleep 1
gsettings set org.mate.font-rendering antialiasing $antialiasing
```

An example script for KDE is this:

```
xrdb -load /home/fabian/misc/antiantialiasing.bak
cd /home/fabian
env WINEPREFIX="/home/fabian/.wine" wine C:\\windows\\command\\start.exe /Unix /home/fabian/.wine/dosdevices/c:/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/Start\ Menu/Programs/Notepad++.lnk "$1"
sleep 1
xrdb -load /home/fabian/misc/antialiasing.bak
```

Here `antialiasing.bak` is just a text file containing »`Xft.antialias: 1`« and `antiantialiasing.bak` is a text file containing »`Xft.antialias: 0`«.

This method would probably also work like this or similar in Mate, but I haven't tested it and the `gsettings` method seems more clean/intended. I have not found such a method for KDE yet.